# Javascript helper method for generating select tag based on provided values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a helper method in my JS toolkit that looks like this

```
var selectOptionValues = [" ","NA","Yes","No"];
var selectedValue = "No";


function CreateSelectList(selectId,selectOptionValues,selectedValue){
// build the selectlist
// if the selectedValue is not null make this value selected
// return select tag
}
```

I am tried to do something like `selectedOption = selectTag[selectedValue]` and then `selecteOption.selected = true` but its not working.

Comment: Don't you need to build this with DOM instead of just assigning?

Comment: @Gunner: When i create a dom element like a div i will use a method like this and append it as child to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're generating option by creating DOM nodes and the part that isn't working, is the selected state of the No option. Try selectOption.setAttribute("selected","selected") - roughly...

```
var selectOptionValues = [" ","NA","Yes","No"], selectedValue = "No";

function CreateSelectList(selectId,selectOptionValues,selectedValue){
    var selectList = document.createElement("select"), selectOption;
    for (var i=0, totalOptions = selectOptionValues.length; i < totalOptions ; i++) {
        selectOption = document.createElement("option");
        selectOption.value = selectOptionValues[i];
        selectOption.innerText = selectOptionValues[i];
        if (selectOptionValues[i] == selectedValue) {
            selectOption.setAttribute("selected","selected");
        }
        selectList.appendChild(selectOption);
    };
    return selectList;
}
```

Comment: "selectOption.setAttribute", is this from JQuery?

Comment: No - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute The jQuery equivalent is probably their attr() method from memory.

Comment: Besides the point of the original question, a sub question, should selectOption.innerText in my example be selectOption.nodeValue?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to method Dean Burge suggested, you can also set the default value by `selectedIndex` property of select object. If you make selectedValue the index of desired value, it becomes pretty simple:

```
//selectedValue==3;
yourPopulatedSelect.selectedIndex=selectedValue;
//"No" will be selected
```